# Rails batch convert one object to another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I am looking for the most efficient way (in speed) to converts a huge number of objects (1M instances) to another object type.
Unfortunately I don't have the choice of what I am getting as an input (the million object).

So far I've tried with `each_slice` but it does not show much improvement when it comes to speed!

It looks like this:

```rb
expected_objects_of_type_2 = []
huge_array.each_slice(3000) do |batch|
  batch.each do |object_type_1|
    expected_objects_of_type_2 << NewType2.new(object_type_1)
  end  
end
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual scenario for this? Bulk imports?

Comment: The batches are treated sequentially. You should treat each slice in a thread.

Comment: `each_slice` doesn't seem to be a good idea here - you already have the whole initial array in memory, so the most efficient way to iterate over it is just to iterate :) `each_slice` will create many additional arrays that have to be garbage-collected then - this adds some unnecessary overhead.

Comment: _improvement_  : What kind of "improvement" are you looking for? Speed?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick test with a few different methods of looping the array and measured the timings:

```
huge_array = Array.new(10000000){rand(1..1000)}
a = Time.now
string_array = huge_array.map{|x| x.to_s}
b = Time.now
puts b-a
```

Same with:

```
sa = []
huge_array.each do |x|
    sa << x.to_s
end
```

and

```
sa = []
huge_array.each_slice(3000) do |batch|
  batch.each do |x|
    sa << x.to_s
  end  
end
```

No idea what you are converting so I did a bit of simple int to string.

Timings

```
Map: 1.7
Each: 2.3
Slice: 3.2
```

So apparently your slice overhead makes things slower. Map seems to be the fastest (which is internally just a for loop but with a non-dynamic length array as output). The `<<` seems to slow things down a bit.

So if each object needs an individual converting you are stuck with O(n) complexity and can't speed things up by a lot. Just avaid overhead.

Depending on your data, sorting and exploiting caching effects might help or avoiding duplicates if you have a lot of identical data but we have no way to know if we don't know your actual conversions.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Actually there are no duplicates so I can't save much there... 
That's interesting to see the map more performing here. I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

I would treat each slice in its own thread:

```
huge_array.each_slice(3000) do |batch|
  Thread.new do 
    batch.each do |object_type_1|
      expected_objects_of_type_2 << NewType2.new(object_type_1)
    end  
  end
end
```

Then you have to wait for the threads to terminate using `join`. They should be accumulated in an array and joined.

Comment: It might be even slower than the initial implementation: because of GIL only one of the spawned threads will be executed at any particular moment + threads machinery overhead (including context switching cost)

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot about it. Then I would try Ruby 3 Ractors.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov : Would this apply even on a system with several more than one core?